# Retrieving joystick name with win32 api

Tags: c, winapi, windows-vista

I have a joystick plugged in. It has a name string "My 50cent Joystick" that shows up if I go to Game Controllers under the Control Panel on Vista. I want to retrieve this string programmatically. After some research I found joyGetDevCaps that can retrieve a lot of information except the name string. Under szPname I get "Microsoft Pc Joystick driver" and under some information. Under szOEMVxD array i get what looks like "pc joystick driver" surrounded by random characters. How do I get the name that shows up under the control panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm...

Perhaps try [enumerating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206128(VS.85).aspx) the joysticks on the system. The [DIDEVICEINSTANCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219639(VS.85).aspx) that gets passed to your callback function might have the string you're looking for in its tszInstanceName or tszProductName fields.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid directinput but it looks like there is no way. Your method works.